# Bluetooth Low Energy with EXPO React-native

Tags: reactjs, bluetooth, expo, native

Expo Posted this https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/bluetooth-1

Here is my code:https://github.com/kimmyyyyyyyyyyyyy/hello--world-

When I run react-native-ble-plx on my project, or even a Simple Hello World project, I get following error:

> Unable to resolve module fs from /Users/user/Downloads/hello,-world!/node_modules/@config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx/node_modules/@expo/config-plugins/build/utils/XML.js: fs could not be found within the project or in these directories:

All I'm running on App.js is:

```
import {

BleError,

BleManager,

Characteristic,

Device,

} from '@config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx';

const bleManager = new BleManager();

console.log(bleManager);
```

Any idea what this is and how to fix this?

I am trying to solve this error.